# Block certain files from being uploaded

Tags: php

I need to stop php, pl, cgi from being uploaded to my website. How is this possible? I've tried so many weird things and I have no hope for it, I never get it to work.

So yes, php, pl and cgi needs to be blocked.

Code:

```html
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * Handles POST uploads, generates filenames, moves files around and commits
 * uploaded metadata to database.
 */

require_once 'classes/Response.class.php';
require_once 'classes/UploadException.class.php';
require_once 'classes/UploadedFile.class.php';
require_once 'includes/database.inc.php';

/**
 * Generates a random name for the file, retrying until we get an unused one.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 *
 * @return string
 */
function generateName($file)
{
    global $db;
    global $doubledots;

    // We start at N retries, and --N until we give up
    $tries = POMF_FILES_RETRIES;
    $length = POMF_FILES_LENGTH;
    $ext = pathinfo($file->name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if extension is a double-dot extension and, if true, override $ext
    $revname = strrev($file->name);
    foreach ($doubledots as $ddot) {
        if (stripos($revname, $ddot) === 0) {
            $ext = strrev($ddot);
        }
    }

    do {
        // Iterate until we reach the maximum number of retries
        if ($tries-- === 0) {
            throw new Exception(
                'Gave up trying to find an unused name',
                500
            ); // HTTP status code "500 Internal Server Error"
        }

        $chars = ID_CHARSET;
        $name = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $name .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars))];
        }

        // Add the extension to the file name
        if (isset($ext) && $ext !== '') {
            $name .= '.'.$ext;
        }

        // Check if a file with the same name does already exist in the database
        $q = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(filename) FROM files WHERE filename = (:name)');
        $q->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();
        $result = $q->fetchColumn();
    // If it does, generate a new name
    } while ($result > 0);

    return $name;
}

/**
 * Handles the uploading and db entry for a file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 *
 * @return array
 */
function uploadFile($file)
{
    global $db;
    global $FILTER_MODE;
    global $FILTER_MIME;

    // Handle file errors
    if ($file->error) {
        throw new UploadException($file->error);
    }

    // Check if mime type is blocked
    if (!empty($FILTER_MIME)) {
        if ($FILTER_MODE == true) { //whitelist mode
            if (!in_array($file->mime, $FILTER_MIME)) {
                throw new UploadException(UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
            }
        } else { //blacklist mode
            if (in_array($file->mime, $FILTER_MIME)) {
                throw new UploadException(UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION);
            }
        }
    }


    // Check if a file with the same hash and size (a file which is the same)
    // does already exist in the database; if it does, return the proper link
    // and data. PHP deletes the temporary file just uploaded automatically.
    $q = $db->prepare('SELECT filename, COUNT(*) AS count FROM files WHERE hash = (:hash) '.
                      'AND size = (:size)');
    $q->bindValue(':hash', $file->getSha1(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':size', $file->size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->execute();
    $result = $q->fetch();
    if ($result['count'] > 0) {
        return array(
            'hash' => $file->getSha1(),
            'name' => $file->name,
            'url' => POMF_URL.rawurlencode($result['filename']),
            'size' => $file->size,
        );
    }

    // Generate a name for the file
    $newname = generateName($file);

    // Store the file's full file path in memory
    $uploadFile = POMF_FILES_ROOT . $newname;

    // Attempt to move it to the static directory
    if (!move_uploaded_file($file->tempfile, $uploadFile)) {
        throw new Exception(
            'Failed to move file to destination',
            500
        ); // HTTP status code "500 Internal Server Error"
    }

    // Need to change permissions for the new file to make it world readable
    if (!chmod($uploadFile, 0644)) {
        throw new Exception(
            'Failed to change file permissions',
            500
        ); // HTTP status code "500 Internal Server Error"
    }

    // Add it to the database
    if (empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        // Query if user is NOT logged in
        $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO files (hash, originalname, filename, size, date, ' .
                    'expire, delid) VALUES (:hash, :orig, :name, :size, :date, ' .
                        ':exp, :del)');
    } else {
        // Query if user is logged in (insert user id together with other data)
        $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO files (hash, originalname, filename, size, date, ' .
                    'expire, delid, user) VALUES (:hash, :orig, :name, :size, :date, ' .
                        ':exp, :del, :user)');
        $q->bindValue(':user', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    // Common parameters binding
    $q->bindValue(':hash', $file->getSha1(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':orig', strip_tags($file->name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':name', $newname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':size', $file->size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':date', date('Y-m-d'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':exp', null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':del', sha1($file->tempfile), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();

    return array(
        'hash' => $file->getSha1(),
        'name' => $file->name,
        'url' => POMF_URL.rawurlencode($newname),
        'size' => $file->size,
    );
}

/**
 * Reorder files array by file.
 *
 * @param  $_FILES
 *
 * @return array
 */
function diverseArray($files)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($files as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Reorganize the $_FILES array into something saner.
 *
 * @param  $_FILES
 *
 * @return array
 */
function refiles($files)
{
    $result = array();
    $files = diverseArray($files);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $f = new UploadedFile();
        $f->name = $file['name'];
        $f->mime = $file['type'];
        $f->size = $file['size'];
        $f->tempfile = $file['tmp_name'];
        $f->error = $file['error'];
        //$f->expire   = $file['expire'];
        $result[] = $f;
    }

    return $result;
}

$type = isset($_GET['output']) ? $_GET['output'] : 'json';
$response = new Response($type);

if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploads = refiles($_FILES['files']);


    try {
        foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
            $res[] = uploadFile($upload);
        }
        $response->send($res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response->error($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    $response->error(400, 'No input file(s)');
}
```

How?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no control over files before they are actually uploaded to server. Your web server will handle the file upload and then give access to the php file to do any action. All you can do with php is check mime type / file extension to check if file uploaded is valid and delete if not a valid file we need.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) provided by the PHP group regarding file uploads.

One thing you will also want to keep in mind is that the mime type provided on upload is set by the client browser and is based on the file extension; ie .txt = ascii/txt, or .jpg = image/jpg.

Very easy to spoof the mime type so take the necessary precausions by making use of the [fileinfo class of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to more accurately determine the file type once uploaded.